# end() vs cend()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Всегда ли это предложение возвращает `true` для стандартных контейнеров?

```
container.end() == container.cend();
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Is comparison of const_iterator with iterator well-defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35390835/4279)

Comment: @jfs добавила метку для `c++14`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, всегда. Итераторы, указывающие на одно и то же положение в контейнере, должны быть равными, даже если они отличаются по типу (обычный vs. константаный).

См. 23.2.1/7

> In the expressions
>       i == j
>       i != j
>       i < j
>       i <= j
>       i >= j
>       i > j
>       i - j
>   where `i` and `j` denote objects of a container’s `iterator` type, either or both may be replaced by an object of the container’s `const_iterator` type referring to the same element **with no change in semantics**.

Comment: А всегда ли должны эти самые типы быть вообще сравнимыми?

Comment: @VladD получается, [да](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390835/is-comparison-of-const-iterator-with-iterator-well-defined)